# handling relations in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
rel(X,Y) :- dep(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- aux(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- auxpass(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- cop(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- conj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- cc(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- arg(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- subj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- nsubj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- nsubjpass(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- csubj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- comp(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- obj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- dobj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- iobj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- pobj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- attr(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- ccomp(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- xcomp(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- compl(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- mark(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- acomp(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- agent1(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- ref1(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- expl(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- mod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- advcl(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- purpcl(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- tmod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- rcmod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- amod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- infmod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- partmod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- num(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- number(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- appos(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- nn(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- abbrev(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- advmod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- neg(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- poss(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- possesive(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- prt(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- det(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- prep(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- sdep(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- xsubj(X,Y).

related(X,Z) :- rel(X,Y), rel(Y,Z).
```

but in the last relation i want the first "rel" to be different from the next "rel"
how to check if they are distinct.. please help

Comment: You want the instntiated variables to be different or the relation itself to be different ?

Comment: relation itself should be different.. not variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are predicates, so they either hold or not. In Prolog you don't distinguish different occurences of them. So "different" can only apply to their arguments, which is easy to achieve by adding that they should be .. well.. different:

`rel(X,Y), rel(Y,Z), rel(X,Y) \= rel(Y,Z)`

Keep it mind that there are different operators available for "not equal". You'd have to give a clearer definition of what you want to determine the right one.

Edit:
I just read the comments that you want the actual relation to differ. You should then somehow transport that relation upwards. Here's a suggestion:

Replace `rel/2` by `rel/3` like this: `rel(X,Y, Type) :- Type = dep, dep(X,Y).`
Then you can ensure differing relations with `rel(X,Y,Type1), rel(X,Y,Type2), Type1 \= Type2`.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two ways.
If you are allowed to change the rel/2 predicates you might want to add a new argument to return also the relation involved.
Instead of

```
rel(X,Y):- dep(X,Y).
rel(X,Y):- aux(X,Y).
```

put something like

```
rel(X,Y, dep):- dep(X,Y).
rel(X,Y, aux):- aux(X,Y).
```

and then in related/2 use something like this:

```
related(X,Z):- rel(X,Y, R1), rel(Y, Z, R2), R1 \= R2.
```

If you are not allowed to change the rel/2 predicate then you might do it with some other tricks, changing related/2 to something like:

```
related(X, Z):-
    clause(rel(X,Y), A), 
    clause(rel(Y,Z), B), 
    call(A), call(B), 
    functor(A,Fa,_), functor(B, Fb, _), 
    Fa \= Fb.
```

Answer (score 2):

@Nir: As a general remark, instead of `R1 =..[X,A,B], call(R1)` it is often
preferable to write `call(X,A,B)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a prolog newbie, but thought this was a nice problem. My solution has somesimilarities  to the answer above, you could use something like this:

```
related(A,C,List):- member(X,List),
               member(Y,List),
               not(X=Y),
               R1=..[X,A,B],
               R2=..[Y,B,C],
               call(R1),
               call(R2).
```

You would then call it with `isRelated(X,Y):-related(X,Y,[prt,det,.......])`